# Form Validation using jQuery Validation in Jade template

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate, pug

I am using nodejs and Jade for its template. I need to have form validation.

I have this in my jade file:

```
form(action='/course/create', method='post', id='createForm')
    table#profile
        tr
            td.left
                label(for='courseNum') Course Number *
            td.right
                input#courseNum.inputBox2(type='text', name='courseNum')
        tr
            td.left
                 label(for='courseName') Course Name *
            td.right
                 input#courseName.inputBox2(type='text', name='courseName')
        tr
            td.left
            td.right
                 button#btnSubmit(type='submit') SUBMIT

script(src='/javascript/jquery-1.9.1.js').
script(src='/javascript/jquery.validate.js').
script.
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#createForm').validate({
            rules: {
                courseNum : "required",
                courseName : "required"
            },
            messages : {
                courseNum : "Required!",
                courseName : "Required!"
            }
        });
    });
```

But I dont know why there are no errors showing up. Yes, the form do not submit when it is not valid, but there are no errors showing up. And the form also do not submit when it is valid. But when I remove the validation, It does submit. So the problem is in the validation.

What I am missing?

Here is the rendered source code from the browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/typography.css">
        <script src="/javascript/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="/javascript/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>
    <form id="createForm" action="/course/create" method="post">
        <table class="profile">
            <tr>
                <td class="left">
                      <label for="courseNum">Course Number *</label>
                </td>
                <td class="right">
                       <input id="courseNum" type="text" name="courseNum" class="inputBox2">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <td class="left">
                       <label for="courseName">Course Name *</label>
                 </td>
                 <td class="right">
                        <input id="courseName" type="text" name="courseName" class="inputBox2">
                 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                  <td class="left">
                  </td>
                  <td class="right">
                       <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
                  </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
   </form>   
       <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#createForm').validate({
                rules: {
                    courseNum : "required",
                    courseName : "required"
                },
                messages : {
                    courseNum : "Required!",
                    courseName : "Required!"
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope we can find I am missing.. Please help.
When I remove the validation, it submits the form.
But when there is validation, even it is valid or not, it doesnt submit, and no errors.

Comment: Does the browser show any javascript errors in the console?

Comment: Please, this is a client-side issue so only show the client-side code.    In other words, show the JavaScript and HTML **as seen by the browser**.

Comment: @Sparky I just edited the question now with the "view page source" from the browser. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I don't know how to help you.  The code you posted is already working perfectly:  http://jsfiddle.net/Zg7zA/

Comment: Yeah agree, I tried it out with nodejs and jade 1.3.0 and it works perfectly, too. BTW: remove the dot after including jquery and validate with the script tag, you only need the dot if you write plain html/css/javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
     $('#createForm').validate({
        rules: {
            courseNum : "required",
            courseName : "required"
        },
        messages : {
            courseNum : "Required!",
            courseName : "Required!"
        },
         submitHandler: function(form){
         form.submit();
        }
    });
```

or better

```
     $('#createForm').validate({
        rules: {
            courseNum  : { required:true },
            courseName : { required:true }
        },
        messages : {
            courseNum : "Required!",
            courseName : "Required!"
        },
         submitHandler: function(form){
         form.submit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: One is not "better" than the other and the `submitHandler` callback is not mandatory.  The OP's code should be working as he posted it, although he needs to show us the code as rendered in the browser to be sure.